# form is always submit using get method MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i m trying to login from a dropdown on navigation bar but when i click on `signin` button the form is submited as get method although i defined `FormMethod.Post` but still it is submited using get method and all the values are visible in `QueryString`
here is my code and image
[image]

and after clicking `Signin`
[image]

**CODE:**

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("Login","Auth",FormMethod.Post,null))
            {
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Email,new{@style = "margin-bottom: 15px;",@placeholder = "Email address",@size = "30",@type = "email",@required = ""})

 @Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password,new{@style = "margin-bottom: 15px;",@placeholder = "Password",@size = "30"})

 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @style = "float: left; margin-right: 10px;" })
 @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.RememberMe)
 <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
            }
```

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string returl)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ViewBag.returl = returl;
            return View();
        }
        string[] arr1 = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
        foreach (var v in arr1)
        {
            if (v.Contains("Administrator"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Login log, string returl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(log.Email, log.Password))
        {
            if (((MyMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).IsActive(log.Email))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(log.Email, log.RememberMe);
                string[] arr = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(log.Email);
                if (returl != null)
                {
                    foreach (var v in arr)
                    {
                        if (v.Contains("Administrator"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Redirect(returl);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var v in arr)
                    {
                        if (v.Contains("Administrator"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please confirm ur email to Login!!!!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password!!!");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**SOLUTION:**
the error was being caused because the main page contain a form tag in which partial view is rendered which causes it to redirect to home page(index function)

Comment: Show come controller code. How can you be sure it is submitted using get method?

Comment: becoz=>because if it is summited using `GETMETHOD` then the user should get logged in
and also `parameters` value in `QueryString` is also not visible

Comment: "becoz" is not a word so I am not sure what you mean by that, please elaborate. In regards to the rest of your comment, there are lots of things that can cause a query string to have parmaeters. Please edit your question and add some controller code, including any method attributes you are using

Comment: check again question is updated

Comment: OK, so put a breakpoint in both of those methods. That will confirm which one is fired when you login. If `HttpPost` is executed, then step though it and find out where the query parameters are coming from. What happens when you login with invalid credentials?

Comment: instead of triggering login it trigger index function

Comment: Do you have nested html forms, or something like that which might cause the problem? Did you put breakpoints at the very start of your Login methods? (as they might be causing the redirect to index)

Comment: this login is partial view
masterpage didnt contain any other form

Comment: I don't think I can help anymore. Your question does contain enough information to replicate the problem, and I don't want to have to recreate your entire project just to work it out. You will have to try and debug the problem at your end

Comment: when i click sign from navigation that error occurs
but when i include that partialview to a controller then signin then it works correctly